# PhoneGap how to include JavaScript file from internal storage of application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-sdk-2.3

I have a JavaScript file say "include.js" in my internal Storage of Application.

In my index.html file to include any javascript file we use:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="include.js"></script>
```

But how can i give src as the file that i have in my internal storage i.e. include.js

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but the answer is you can include it with

```
<script src="file:///mnt/sdcard/include.js"
```